# Can any one identify this shrub from these leaves pics?

Tags: shrubs

Can any one identify this tree from these leaves pics?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @Niali C, I don't think this is Prunus or Malus...This is Alnus cordata  ummmmm the Italian Alder.  Can't see the margins very well and couldn't find the catkins.  What do you think?

Comment: If I could feel the underside of the leaf this just might be serrulata which has a propensity to grow in thickets.

Comment: @Sachin If you would go out and take a picture of the lower side of some leaves...and if you could find any catkins?